# Get countries borders longitude latitude coordinates

Tags: python, geolocation, geospatial, geocoding, geo

I'm trying to find a CSV file of borders in  coordinates. 
I need the file to be with highest resolution possible,
as I have many coordinates, and I need to calculate their exact distance from the sea.
I found some datasets but they either were low-resolution or in a format I don't know to read.
I'm interested in only one state borders (Israel, in my case). 
Any help would be appreciated.
I'm a Python programmer so if there is a package in python that has it it will be great.

Comment: Are saying you don't want to deal with shape files?  http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php

Comment: CSV are probably not the format you'll find this data in. While its possible, its not as common. Your best bet is to find shapefiles containing the area you are looking for and then using geopandas, ogr or fionia. If you can also use a gui like qgis. The usgs has some good data https://www.usgs.gov/products/data-and-tools/gis-data

Comment: @Ywapom - I'd prefer not to, unless I have to.Plus,  the data in the file you mentioned are in a very low resolution (at least for Israel borders).

Comment: @Taylor - I looked at the site you mentioned, and found data only on the US. Are you sure there is also data for the rest of the world in it?

Comment: @BinyaminEven I apologize I saw states but overlooked the Israel part. As the name implaies it is only us data but this should help find what you need https://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/

Comment: @Taylor again, low resolution :(

Comment: @BinyaminEven by resolution you mean the base map resolution? are you looking to be able to view houses and cars on the road type detail?

Comment: @Taylor no, I'm just looking to get detailed enough line, and not ~10 coordinates with rough lines, as I need to calculate, pretty accurately, distance from the see for many coordinates.

Comment: @BinyaminEven Chat?